# Find all dynamic checkboxes that are checked

Tags: jquery

This is what I tried.

```
var items = $jointlist.find("input[id*='_conf']").filter(function() { 
  return this.checked == 'true' 
});
```

but im unsure about the `this.checked == 'true'` bit

Comment: Try `({return this.checked;});`

Comment: Why a filter? [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) exists.

Comment: you can use just - `var list = $jointlist.find("input[id*='_conf']:checked")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use [:checked-selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) like,

```
var items = $jointlist.find("input[id*='_conf']:checked")
```

Comment: Liked this. Short and clean :)